How to proof that $\sqrt 2 ^{\sqrt 2} $ is irrational
So far I've written
Using proof by contradiction:
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Imagine $\sqrt 2 ^ \sqrt 2$ being equal to $\frac{a}{b}$.
$a = b \cdot \sqrt 2 ^ \sqrt 2 $
$a ^ {\sqrt 2} = (b \cdot \sqrt 2 ^ \sqrt 2) ^ \sqrt2 = b ^ \sqrt 2 \cdot 2 $
Then power both sides again by $\sqrt 2$
$a ^  2 = b ^  2 \cdot 2 ^ \sqrt 2$
Now, I have a sense that this is impossible - and the proof is right - but we still don't know $2 ^ \sqrt 2$ is irrational. Am I on the right track? How to prove that $2 ^ \sqrt 2$ is irrational if the proof is right until here?

This question is not precalculus level.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem

or see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant

And here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventh_problem.

The Gelfond–Schneider theorem states: if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers and $\beta$ is irrational, then $\alpha^\beta$ is transcendental. It is worth noting this doesn't hold for trivial cases such as $\alpha=0$ or $1$ for obvious reasons.
Using this theorem we can examine the number $2^\sqrt 2$, known as the Gelfond-Schneider constant. Both $2$ and $\sqrt2$ are algebraic and $\sqrt2$ is irrational, therefore $2^\sqrt2$ is transcendental, as well as its square root $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$. All real transcendental numbers are irrational, meaning $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is irrational.
This was first proved by Rodion Kuzmin in the 1930's. I have attached an outline of his proof as well as Gelfond's here. I would also recommend reading the Wikipedia articles linked in the comments, specifically the Gelfond-Schneider theorem and the Gelfond-Schneider constant.

Such an interesting topic! Thanks!
